# Custom Auth using AWS Cognito, Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use AWS Cognito for password less signin/signup using mobile number.

Signin/Signup steps:

1. User submits only mobile number
2. After receiving the passcode via sms, the user submits that to signin/signup.

To achieve the above, as there is no example code for mobile number only Signin, I am trying to amend the standard sign up (email, password)  code shown in this [aws sdk github example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift/CognitoYourUserPoolsSample/SignUpViewController.swift).

Can someone please advice what changes are to be made to achieve signin via mobile number only (no e-mail or username).

```
import Foundation
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?
    var sentTo: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.init(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let signUpConfirmationViewController = segue.destination as? ConfirmSignUpViewController {
            signUpConfirmationViewController.sentTo = self.sentTo
            signUpConfirmationViewController.user = self.pool?.getUser(self.username.text!)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        guard let userNameValue = self.username.text, !userNameValue.isEmpty,
            let passwordValue = self.password.text, !passwordValue.isEmpty else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Missing Required Fields",
                                                        message: "Username / Password are required for registration.",
                                                        preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(okAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
                return
        }

        var attributes = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]()

        if let phoneValue = self.phone.text, !phoneValue.isEmpty {
            let phone = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
            phone?.name = "phone_number"
            phone?.value = phoneValue
            attributes.append(phone!)
        }

        if let emailValue = self.email.text, !emailValue.isEmpty {
            let email = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
            email?.name = "email"
            email?.value = emailValue
            attributes.append(email!)
        }



        //sign up the user
        self.pool?.signUp(userNameValue, password: passwordValue, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil).continueWith {[weak self] (task) -> Any? in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let error = task.error as? NSError {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: error.userInfo["__type"] as? String,
                                                            message: error.userInfo["message"] as? String,
                                                            preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(retryAction)

                    self?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
                } else if let result = task.result  {
                    // handle the case where user has to confirm his identity via email / SMS
                    if (result.user.confirmedStatus != AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.confirmed) {
                        strongSelf.sentTo = result.codeDeliveryDetails?.destination
                        strongSelf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "confirmSignUpSegue", sender:sender)
                    } else {
                        let _ = strongSelf.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                    }
                }

            })
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as you are facing.